# Oracle job scheduler create program to create/drop materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to implement a program that will invoke the Oracle job scheduler that runs the following block of code:

```
create materialized view foo  
parallel  
nologging  
never refresh  
as  
select * from long_running_query;
```

and subsequently

```
drop materialized view foo;
```

Now the logical flow I am looking at is as follows:

1)  Oracle Scheduler fires every thirty (30) minutes.
2)  New materialized view is generated with arbitrary name (bar)
3)  Bar is passed into the create function as above (create mat view bar... )
4)  The view (regular not materialized) outside_view is dropped
5)  outside_view is recreated to point at the materialized view created in step 3

My issue is that I have not been able to get this to run within PL/SQL or as an executable.

Comment: Why not `REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND` with a scheduler that invokes the refresh command? Do you need data historization?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat   The amount of time to refresh is far too long.  These views get crushed every thirty minutes and I am dealing with hundreds of millions of rows

Comment: Creating a materialized view will take just as long as refreshing an existing one. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh ok, it's true that performance for standard refresh (delete+insert) will be problematic for so many rows -- whereas DROP+CREATE nolog parallel will be much faster and will generate a lot less undo/redo.

Comment: See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:15695764787749 for a possible solution.

Comment: @Colin'tHart that isn't true in the least.  If I have indexes on my MV and I am refreshing ~25%+ of my MV there will be a large amount of redo generated.  Source: running things in test.

Comment: Aah, silly me, I've even done that myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure with regular use of dynamic SQL should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refresh_mv(p_mv_name VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p_mv_name) || '
      PARALLEL
      NOLOGGING
      NEVER REFRESH
      AS
      SELECT * FROM <biq_query>';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW outside_view AS SELECT * FROM '||p_mv_name;
   -- DROP old mv?
END;
```

Comment: what is `connect by level <= 5`

Comment: @Woot4Moo just a quick query to test that it would work on my system. Replace with your query.

Comment: It *is* a kind of Oracle trick, but not at all related to this question :) try `SELECT * FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level <= 5`

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use an ordinary refresh path as follows:

```
create materialized view foo
parallel
nologging
refresh complete
as  
select /*+ append */ * from long_running_query;
```

Then when needing to refresh:

1. Disable all indexes on foo
2. Refresh foo
3. Rebuild the indexes, preferably with nologging.

Comment: I think the refresh complete will be either DELETE+INSERT (lots or redo) or TRUNCATE+INSERT. The first case is impractical here and in the second case, there will be a downtime : the MV will be empty during the refresh.

Comment: Right again... there are some many things to consider! There are many of these cases where people are inventing all of these work-arounds -- one would hope Oracle would come up with some features to automate some of these.